# Net::SNMP caching results for extend OIDs

Tags: linux, perl, snmp, net-snmp

The scope of this work is to query two machines' high resolution timer at the "same time" and get the time clock inaccuracy between both systems. This is done by having the 3rd machine sending an SNMP-get for a custom OID where the SNMP agent is configured to invoke a perl script to return the high-resolution timer. All works fine as in the snmp-get manages to return the expected result. However it appears that regardless of the frequency of the snmpget queries, the snmpagent only performs a fresh query to the script at ~5 second intervals. I am running NET SNMP version 5.4.3. After some research I've seen that this is typical of NET SNMP to cache the results and this is done on MIB tree basis. There is MIB (nsCacheTable) with the respective intervals by querying snmpwalk to 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.5.3. Apparently the values can be changed to 0 to remove caching. Some of these are read-only though. Although I've set a few of them to 0 using SNMPset (as most of them return a Bad object type error).
I know very basic SNMP so I followed a guide online and mapped the below custom OID to the perl script with this line in the snmpd.conf.

```
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.27654.3 return_date /usr/bin/perl [directory]/[perl script name].pl
```

Then the actual OID containing the output (time in epoch) is:
iso.3.6.1.4.1.27654.3.3.1.1.11.114.101.116.117.114.110.95.100.97.116.101

Anyone has any ideas how I can disable the caching for this OID?

Thanks in advance.

---EDIT---

According to [this](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp.html) blog post, in order to avoid disabling the caching - one can instead use pass-persist scripts which look more complex to implement at first glance. The perl script I used to call is the below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# THIS SCRIPT RETURNS THE EPOCH TIME OF DAY IN MICROSECONDS

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
($s, $usec) = gettimeofday();

$newtime = $s.$usec;
print ($newtime);
```

Anyone can provide help in converting this script for pass-persist and how the snmpd.conf should look like?

Comment: Why would you do clock synchronization with SNMP? This seems like a very poorly thought-out systems design. There are so many situations where SNMP is not reliable in terms of delivery assurance or timing...

Comment: It is not doing clock synchronization via SNMP. It is querying the high resolution time of a system via SNMP. The intent is to send this query to two machines at the "same time".